# Spring Assistant does not show Intellij 2021

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

I just installed Intellij 2021.2.2 and I want to start a Spring Project with Spring Assistant.

I searched in the plugins Spring Assistant but it does not show in the results.

[Screenshot Intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iwA4.png)

Thank you !

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Spring projects are created via the Spring Initializr: https://i.imgur.com/saGvA5P.png. Is that what you need?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I do not have Spring Initializr either

Comment: Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html. Do you use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate or Community?

Comment: I have got Community Edition

Comment: Spring support is available only in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, see https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html.

Comment: I used to have Spring support on Intellij before I think, I did't know it changed... Thank you though !

Comment: It didn't change, Community edition never had Spring support.